# bootstrap - tooltip break td style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The tooltip breaks the width of td.

Please see this **Fiddle** snippet http://jsfiddle.net/zhoujiealex/1d1bm9kc/

I want to show tooltip when mouse hover on truncated text in table.

I refere this post [Show Bootstrap Tooltip Over Truncated Text](http://chadkuehn.com/show-tooltip-over-truncated-text/)

The difference is that above post use a `<div>` embed in `<td>`.

In my current project, old codes used `<td>` directly.
The tooltip can show up, but it breaks the width of table. It's so wired.

No tooltip
[image]

tooltip shows:
[image]

Anyone can show me the right direction?

Comment: It is because tooltip div is added inside tr when you hover. Try to add tooltip div outside tr. And suggest that if possible use DIV structure instead of DIV.

Comment: just make div in your td and it's work fine. `<td><div>abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-Hello Wolrd!</div></td>` and `$(document).on('mouseenter', "table.table-striped > tbody > tr > td > div", function () {
  `

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant  thanks,  I have tried <div>, and it works, but it needs to change lots of td element in current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `container: 'body'` in your code

```
$this.tooltip({
   title: $this.text(),
   placement: "bottom",
   container: 'body'
});
```

Check this out: [http://jsfiddle.net/zhoujiealex/1d1bm9kc/](http://jsfiddle.net/1d1bm9kc/17/)

Read More: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips

Answer (score 0):

You could use `a` or `span` tags inside `td` and apply tooltip/popover to it.
This will not break the tds of your table.

Or just use the built-in solution `tooltip-append-to-body="true"`

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/580).

Comment: thanks for your link, it explains more detailed info and provide a built-in solution `tooltip-append-to-body="true"`.